# Why am I allowed to cancel terms inside an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the definite integral
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} \ \text{d}\theta
$$
When $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, the integrand becomes
$$
\frac{0}{0}
$$
Since the integral can be thought of as the limit of a Riemann sum and each $\theta$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ will eventually be substituted into the integrand, then would it still be correct to write
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} \ \text{d}\theta = \int_0^{\pi} 1 \ \text{d}\theta
$$
If so, why?

Comment: It is correct to write that.  If you replace a function $f(x)$ on an interval $[a,b]$ with another function $g(x)$ which differs from $f(x)$ at countably many points (or is even undefined at countably many points), then the Riemann integrals of $f$ and $g$ on the intervals $[a,b]$ are equal.  This is because the "rectangles" at those countably many places have area zero.

Comment: Technically the integrand is undefined at that point, but changing the value of the integrand at a single point doesn't affect the area under the curve.

Comment: @D_S is there a name/reference for this theorem?

Comment: It's a very standard result, and very easy to prove yourself in the case of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differing at finitely many points

Comment: @D_S for countably many points it isn't true in general, you'd have to go to the Lebesgue integral (more precisely, one of them may not exist)

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quotient $\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}$ is equal to $1$ if $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)\cup\left(\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$, and it is undefined if $\theta\in\frac\pi2$. So, your integral is actually an improper integral and it is equal to\begin{align}\lim_{\alpha\to\frac\pi2^-}\int_0^\alpha\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta+\lim_{\beta\to\frac\pi2^+}\int_\beta^\pi\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta&=\lim_{\alpha\to\frac\pi2^-}\int_0^\alpha1\,\mathrm d\theta+\lim_{\beta\to\frac\pi2^+}\int_\beta^\pi1\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}1\,\mathrm d\theta+\int_{\pi/2}^\pi1\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^\pi1\,\mathrm d\theta.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

For any bounded function $f$, if $f$ has a discontinuity, then it is still Riemann integrable. The "intuitive" reason is that the "rectangle" there would account for $0$% of the total area, thus it can be neglected.

There is a stronger result: a bounded function $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities has measure $0$.

Comment: Do you have any references for these theorems?

Comment: Technically, as it is currently written in the question the function is undefined at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ so talking about continuity doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mhdadk See https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/Riemann-Lebesgue-Theorem.pdf Theorem 6-11(a)

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis True. Of course, this can be remedied by defining a new function $g$ such that $g(\pi/2)=0$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis But then $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Bonnaduck You're right. I missed that part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

On the interval $[0,\pi],$ the function $\displaystyle\frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta}$ is identically equal to $1$ except at $x=\displaystyle\frac\pi2,$ where it is undefined. Therefore, strictly speaking, $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} \ \text{d}\theta$$ does not exist.

If we change the integrand by introducing the point $\displaystyle\left(\frac\pi2,v\right),$ where $v$ is any real number, into its definition, then it becomes bounded with countably many discontinuities (in fact, with just at most one discontinuity), and thus Riemann-integrable, on $[0,\pi].$ In fact, the integral becomes equal to $\int_0^{\pi} 1\, \ \text{d}\theta,$ whose value is straightforward to compute.